# pyqt5 font-size and dimensions missmatch between QtDesigner (preview mode) and production

Tags: python, pyqt5, size, font-size, qt-designer

[image]

[image]

The first print screen is from Qt Designer (preview mode - style Fusion).

The second print screen is after running `python my_pyqt5_app.py` command (first i run `pyuic5 -x my_pyqt5_app.ui -o my_pyqt5_app.py`

As you can see they are differences between the two images. (Font size and dimensions-sizes).

What's wrong about?

Is there something i can change in qt designer? If no, what code should make the two images be the same?

Answer (score 0):

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import os #<---change-1
    os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1" #<---change-2
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this change did the change i wished.